# Finding the Mean Squared Error of Estimator

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

The positive random variables $X_{1}, X_{2},...X_{n}$ are independent and identically distributed as $Ge(\theta)$.

The maximum likelihood estimator of $\psi = \frac{(1 - \theta)}{\theta}$ is the sample mean $\bar X$.

Prove that the alternative estimator $t(X) = \frac{n \bar X}{n + 1}$ has a smaller mean squared error for estimating $\psi$ than $\bar X$, for all $\theta$.

My attempt:

$bias (\theta) = E(\hat \theta) - \theta$

$bias (\psi) = E(\hat \psi) - \psi$

$E(\bar \psi) = \frac{1 - E(\theta)}{E(\theta)}$

$E(\theta) = \frac{1}{\bar X}$

$E(\bar \psi) = \bar X - 1$

And then I get lost..

Please may someone demonstrate how to find the MSE for one of these estimators and then I can do the other one myself?

Comment: The MSE of a random variable is defined to be the (Bias$)^2$ added to the variance. So you need to find the variance of each estimator as well as the bias for each one. Then you need to calculate the MSE for each of them using this formula. After this, you can compare the MSE for both estimators in order to solve your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I understand the formula and the concept behind the question. It's just that I don't know how to find the bias or the variance of the estimators.

Comment: I cannot see the density, and you seem to have switched from $\eta$ to $\theta$ to $\psi$. Is $\eta$ a scale parameter or a rate parameter?  What is $\theta$ (which seems to be between $0$ and $1$)?

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you for spotting that. I must have gotten two different questions muddled up. I have corrected it now.